Dry skull vs live skull measurement adjustments
I am working on a dataset that has dry skull measurements from a museum's collection (twice as many samples) or a live specimen (less common). As you can imagine, the live specimen are on average a few cm larger due to muscle presence, skin, and fur. What are some statistical approaches I could use to correct for these larger sizes to better fit the dry skull measurements? The skull lengths will be used as a variable in a bigger model.
I thought of 3 potential approaches:

Include skull type as a random effect to account for the variation between these methods

Subtract de difference between the predicted length or some mean for each skull type by sex and age, but this seems way to coarse of an approach.

Adjust the measured skull sizes directly using the residuals obtained from a linear regression model. The residuals were subtracted from the measured skull sizes for live specimens, effectively reducing their size to fit a more "mean" size.


# Linear regression:
lm1 <- lm(Skull_length ~ ns(Age, 3) + Sex + Skull_code, 
          data = Dataframe)

# Get residuals from the linear regression model
residuals <- residuals(lm1)

# Create new data frames for predictions
new_data <- expand.grid(Age = 0:30, 
                        Sex = c("M", "F"),
                        Skull_code = as.factor(1))

# Predict skull length using each model
Predicted_skull_df2 <- new_data %>% 
  mutate(Predicted_skull = predict(lm1, newdata = .)) 

# Add residuals to the mean skull length of skull_code == 1 
# (Dry skulls) for skull_code == 2 (live skulls)
Growth_data <- Growth_data %>%
  left_join(Predicted_skull_df) %>% 
  mutate(Adjusted_skull2 = ifelse(Skull_code == 2, Predicted_skull + 
                                  residuals, Skull_l))

# Create plot to compare adjusted to raw measurements
Growth_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = Skull_l)) +
  geom_point(data = Growth_data %>% 
               filter(Skull_code == 1), aes(x = Age - 0.2), 
   colour = "black", alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_smooth(data = Growth_data %>% 
                filter(Skull_code == 1), colour = "black") +  
  geom_point(data = Growth_data %>% 
               filter(Skull_code == 2), aes(x = Age + 0.2), 
   colour = "purple", alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_smooth(data = Growth_data %>% 
                filter(Skull_code == 2), colour = "purple") +  
  geom_point(aes(y = Adjusted_skull_l), colour = "red", 
                 alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = Adjusted_skull_l), colour = "red") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),  
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9.5),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15)) +
  ylab("Skull length") +
  ylim(180, 500)



Imo adding a dummy variable where, e.g., live skull equals one and zero otherwise would be a parsimonious solution. This would adjust the intercept by skull type and provide an estimate of the magnitude of the differences.
